# How do i show different group of images below a button when the button is clicked on the same page in wordpress?

Tags: plugins

I am working on a WordPress website using elementor page builder plugin to design the website.

I am stuck on creating an image gallery that displays images when a button is clicked on the same page below the button.
The image gallery consists of two rows of four images.
Attached below is the mockup of the page of the website I intend to design.
[image]

Comment: You could treat the buttons as tabs, and there are [tabs widgets](https://docs.elementor.com/article/116-tabs) for Elementor from a quick search. Or you could write your own JavaScript to show and hide groups of content as you click buttons, but I don't know anything about Elementor to point you in the right direction.

Comment: Elementor and other 3rd party plugin support is off topic here, you should seek help through the official channels or an Elementor community

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [a comment by user @rup](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/373828/#comment543241_373828):

> You could treat the buttons as tabs, and there are [tabs widgets](https://docs.elementor.com/article/116-tabs) for Elementor from a quick search.